# How to perform a minimal-allocation conversion of 'Memory<T>' into 'Stream'?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, allocation

There doesn't seem to exist a native way of converting a `Memory<T>` instance into a `Stream` in the framework. Is there a simple way to achieve this using some allocation-free approach that only uses the actual memory from the `Memory<T>` instance, or perhaps a way that leverages only a minimal buffer?

I wasn't able to find any examples going from `Memory<T>` to `Stream`: only the opposite is common since there are several newer overloads on `Stream` that allow handling `Memory<T>` instances.

It seems so intuitive that one would be able to convert from `Memory<>` to `MemoryStream` (due mostly to their names, admittedly) so I was a bit disappointed to find this wasn't the case.

I also wasn't able to find any easy way of creating a `System.IO.Pipelines` `PipeReader` or `PipeWriter` with a `Memory<T>`, as those have a `AsStream` extension.

Comment: Note that `PipeWriter.GetMemory()` exists, as does `Memory<T>.CopyTo`, so you could use these for copying data from a `Memory<T>` to a `PipeWriter` ([see here](https://source.dot.net/#System.IO.Pipelines/System/IO/Pipelines/PipeWriter.cs,113)). `PipeReader` gives you `ReadOnlySequence<byte>`, which will expose a series of `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` instances for you

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use unsafe code:

```cs
private static unsafe void DoUnsafeMemoryStuff<T>(ReadOnlyMemory<T> mem) where T : unmanaged
{
    Stream stream;
    MemoryHandle? memHandle = null;
    GCHandle? byteHandle = null;
    int itemSize = sizeof(T);
    if (MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(memory, out var arr))
    {
        byteHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(arr.Array, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        int offsetBytes = arr.Offset * itemSize;
        int totalBytes = arr.Count * itemSize;
        int streamBytesRemaining = totalBytes - offsetBytes;
        stream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream((byte*)byteHandle.Pointer + offsetBytes, streamBytesRemaining);
    }
    else
    {
        // common path, will be very fast to get the stream setup
        memHandle = mem.Pin();
        stream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream((byte*)memHandle.Pointer, mem.Length * itemSize);
    }
    // use stream like any other stream - you will need to keep your memory object and the handle object alive until your stream usage is complete
    try
    {
        // do stuff with stream
    }
    finally
    {
        // cleanup
        if (memHandle.HasValue) { memHandle.Value.Dispose(); }
        if (byteHandle.HasValue) { byteHandle.Value.Free(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've got a few compiler errors there: `memHandle` vs `handle`, `mem` vs `memory`, and since `memHandle` is nullable you need `.Value`

Comment: Another problem is that if `T` isn't `byte` you can't `new MemoryStream(arr.Array`

Comment: I can't imagine that the first branch is any faster than the second, so I'm not sure that `MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray` buys you anything.

Comment: Concur with @canton7... I would simply put a pin-less branch for 'T = byte/sbyte` (it is possible to cast `sbyte[]` to `byte[]`) and live happily with everything else pinned in the `else` (a pin-less branch should normally help a little the gc)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, the `Memory<T>` might not actually be looking at an array: it might be using a `MemoryManager`, or doing something else.

That said, it's possible to use [`MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.memorymarshal.trygetarray?view=net-5.0) to see whether it does reference an array, and take an optimized path if so:

```
ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.AsMemory();
    
var stream = MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(memory, out var arraySegment)
    ? new MemoryStream(arraySegment.Array, arraySegment.Offset, arraySegment.Count)
    : new MemoryStream(memory.ToArray());
```

Comment: memory.ToArray() path will create a copy of the bytes, something original poster did not want

Comment: @jjxtra Indeed, see the text above: "*That said, it's possible to use MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray to see whether it does reference an array, **and take an optimized path if so**:*". The `ToArray()` is the non-optimized path, the first branch is the optimized path.